# Error "Unexpected token" when run mocha against JSX syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, reactjs

I am kind of new to Javascript programming. I tried writing a test for a script with JSX format, but somewhat it fails with `Unexpected token`.

Here's the test code, I haven't write any test yet.

```
//Rectangle.js
let assert = require('chai').assert,
    path = require('path');

import Rectangle from './Rectangle';
```

And here's the code that needs to be tested

```
//Rectangle.jsx
import React from 'react';

class Rectangle extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
    }
}
```

Here's the error

```
SyntaxError: Rectangle.jsx: Unexpected token (5:11)
  3 | class Rectangle extends React.Component {
  4 |   render() {
> 5 |     return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
    |            ^
  6 |   }
  7 | }
```

Here's the `mocha` command that I got from some articles `nyc mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register Rectangle.js`.

I also uploaded the code on github ([link](https://github.com/petrabarus/js-test-with-java-file-structure/tree/a837558b22f7d567b19ec5f36f73c1663d906975)), so you could see the installed dependencies.

How should I fix this? Is there a step that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `react` preset to you babel config inside package.json

```
"babel": {
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need custom compiler to help you compile jsx code.

You can see the example here: [Mocha-react repo](https://github.com/danvk/mocha-react/blob/master/tests/compiler.js).